# How do I define type mgo objectId using Apache Thrift?

Tags: go, thrift

I'm using Apache Thrift to define a struct.

```
struct Base {
    1:string  ID (go.tag = 'bson:"_id" json:"id,omitempty"')
}
```

After executing the command "thrift --gen go base.thrift"
I want it to look like this.

```
type Base struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id" json:"id,omitempty"`
}
```

bson.ObjectId comes from github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson

```
// NewObjectId returns a new unique ObjectId.
func NewObjectId() ObjectId {
    var b [12]byte
    // Timestamp, 4 bytes, big endian
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b[:], uint32(time.Now().Unix()))
    // Machine, first 3 bytes of md5(hostname)
    b[4] = machineId[0]
    b[5] = machineId[1]
    b[6] = machineId[2]
    // Pid, 2 bytes, specs don't specify endianness, but we use big endian.
    b[7] = byte(processId >> 8)
    b[8] = byte(processId)
    // Increment, 3 bytes, big endian
    i := atomic.AddUint32(&objectIdCounter, 1)
    b[9] = byte(i >> 16)
    b[10] = byte(i >> 8)
    b[11] = byte(i)
    return ObjectId(b[:])
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately you did not really explain what the problem is ... could you add that information?

Comment: I think I misunderstood. I have solved the problem now